# Cant renew to correct certificate after changing hostname with letsencrypt

Tags: lets-encrypt

I have a server on AWS that run apache. I made certificate long time ago with letsencrypt, but my fault is i made it with default hostname(ip-172-26-4-66.eu-central-1.compute.internal).

Now i changed it to correct to match my domain name to unbrokendub.com and after renew certificate with certbot, common name in cert is still ip-172-26-4-66.eu-central-1.compute.internal.

I tried to delete letsencrypt and cerbot, to try to create new accaunt at acme with new install, but it didnt help.

Maybe i miss something?